# How do I recover lost photos from iCloud. They are not in recently deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos, recovery

My sister has lost upwards of 400 pictures in an accidental deleting spree. She deleted the photos from her iPhone and it chose to delete it from iCloud too, which is not a big deal in itself, but they are not in recently deleted. We have 10 days to figure it out, please help!

Comment: Based on what do you assume you have only 10 days left?

Comment: She deleted them about 20 days ago, and they stay in the recently deleted folder for 30 days. Assuming they have the same lifetime after deleting them, we have 10 days.

Comment: They stay in the "recently deleted" folder for 30 days, but I'm not aware of any statement from Apple in regard of what happens afterwards (and whether there is an additional grace period).

Answer (score 2):

Did your sister try logging into iCloud.com to check whether there are some deleted pictures? Use the Apple ID and Passwords to login the website to get it.

If you can't get it from the iCloud.com and the "recently deleted", it's hard to find them back unless you've ever created an iPhone backup. You know the photos that you don't sync to iCloud can be saved to iTunes Backup or iCloud backup. Just restore your device will bring them all back.

Answer (score 1):

If the photo's that are trying to be recovered are taken on a different device make sure iCloud photos are turned on in settings:

> **On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch:**
>
> Go to Settings > [your name] > iCloud.
>
> Tap Photos.
>
> Turn on iCloud Photos.
>
> **On your Mac:**
>
> Go to System Preferences > iCloud.
>
> Next to Photos, click Options.
>
> Select iCloud Photos.
>   After you turn on iCloud Photos, you might need to connect to Wi-Fi
>   and wait a few minutes. Then look for your photos again.
>
> Shown below:
>
> [image]

From [Get help with missing photos](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205912)

Make sure that you are also signed in with the same Apple ID.

> **Unhide your photos:**
>
> **On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch:**
>
> Open the Photos app and go to the Albums tab.
>
> Tap Hidden under Other Albums.
>
> Select the photo or video that you want to unhide.
>
> Tap share icon > Unhide.
>
> **On your Mac:**
>
> Open Photos and in the menu bar, click View > Show Hidden Photo Album.
>
> In the left sidebar, select Hidden.
>
> Select the photo or video that you want to unhide.
>
> Control-click the photo, then choose Unhide Photo. You can also choose
>   Image > Unhide Photo from the menu bar, or press Command-L.
>
> If you use iCloud Photos, the photos that you hide on one device are
>   hidden on your other devices too.

If you organize a photo or video into an album and then delete it from
Photos, it will delete everywhere, including your album.